Are Good and Evil relative or absolute?
I know how most religions would deal with this question.
However, how does philosophy deal with these two concepts?

It is more-or-less relative until it establishes itself in relation to existence itself.

The answers are a mess and completely fail to answer the question. I'll be downvoting any answer that attempts to push its own beliefs and upvoting any answers that attempts to give a survey of the landscape of various philosophers and trends as they apply to moral realism/moral relativism.

Some potentially useful SEP introductions to related concepts: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-relativism/ https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-realism/ https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/concept-evil/ https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequentialism/ https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-virtue/ https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-deontological/

The answers to the older question do not settle the matter. Vote to reopen.

@Hudjefa Note that this question is tagged with philosophy of religion and by the OP. Yet its supposed duplicate is to one on secular morality. Go figure

@Rushi, didn't notice that fine detail. Well, as they say, the devil is in the details. Too, proves the case that there's some relativism to the issue: religion vs secularism, their accounts of ethics/morality.

@Hudjefa I wouldn't have noticed either. (1) Someone tried to edit n remove the tag; (2) The edit appeared in the queue (3) I happened to see it. The coinciding of all 3 is quite unlikely!

Against reopening: If this is going to be reopened, it needs to be far more precise. "How does [secular] philosophy deal with whether good and evil are relative or absolute" is far too broad, the answer is "well, there's thousands of years of different approaches, but most people either say it's relative or absolute or both or neither, or some fifth option, for a variety of different reasons"

I also think @Rushi's tag edit was incorrect. Judgement has no definition and few questions, it should be deleted. philosophy-of-religion is "the nature and existence of God, the examination of religious experience, analysis of religious vocabulary and texts, and the relationship of religion and science", which this isn't. Certainly there are religious answers (insofar as that can be defined) to the nature of good and evil, but the question isn't about the nature of religion. It doesn't make sense to call everything a religious philosopher wrote philosophy-of-religion

The indicated duplicate asks exclusively about secular morality.  This one allows for both. Why is this the duplicate?

I think the OPis right; the two questions are not duplicates.  Question re-opened.

@Kaia A new user made an edit suggestion which involved (1) a grammar correction and (2) removed the user's tags. I accepted the grammar changes but not the tag changes. IOW the tags are not mine.

Tnx @GeoffreyThomas

@Rushi Ah, I understand, apologies.

One way of understanding "absolute" and "relative" is that absolute means having a stable reference outside this ephemeral changing world, whereas relative pertains entirely to concerns within this world.
From here it is a small step towards
absolute = religiously mandated
relative = of secular origins
Below is a selection of some philosophers/thinkers who have said that morality — i.e. our understanding of good and evil — needs a religious basis.  These have a Christian slant. But one could find the same from any other (major) tradition.
1. Immanuel Kant
Without a God and a future life, the moral law would be a mere empty phantom.

If no state of well-being follows [man's] well-doing; then there would be a contradiction between morality and the course of nature. . . Why should I make myself worthy of happiness through morality if there is no being who can give me this happiness? Hence without God I would have to be either a visionary or a scoundrel. I would have to deny my own nature and its eternal moral laws. I would have to cease being a rational man.
Lectures on Philosophical Theology
Even the Holy One of the Gospels must first be compared with our ideal of moral perfection before we can recognize him as such"
Foundations of the Metaphysics of Morals

The first quote makes God necessary to morality; the second makes morality sufficient for religion.
2. Fyodor Dostoevsky

If God does not exist, everything is permitted.
(Variously attributed to) Dostoevsky

3. C.S. Lewis

A man does not call a line crooked unless he has some idea of a straight line.
C.S. Lewis

4. John Henry Newman

Conscience is the aboriginal Vicar of Christ.
John Henry Newman

5. Alasdair MacIntyre's Thought Experiment

Imagine that the natural sciences were to suffer the effects of a catastrophe…. A series of environmental disasters [which] are blamed by the general public on the scientists. This leads to rioting, scientists being lynched by angry mobs, the destruction of laboratories and equipment, the burning of books, and ultimately the decision by the government to end science instruction in schools and universities and to imprison and execute the remaining scientists.
Eventually, enlightened people decide to restore science, but what do they have to work with? Only fragments: bits and pieces of theories, chapters of books, torn and charred pages of articles, hazy memories and damaged equipment with functions that are unclear, if not entirely forgotten. These people, he argues, would combine these fragments as best they could, inventing theories to connect them as necessary. People would talk and act as though they were doing “science,” but they would actually be doing something very different from what we currently call science. From our point of view, in a world where the sciences are intact, their “science” would be full of errors and inconsistencies, “truths” which no one could actually prove, and competing theories which were incompatible with one another. Further, the supporters of these theories would be unable to agree on any way to resolve their differences.


The hypothesis I wish to advance is that in the actual world which we inhabit the language of morality is in the same state of grave disorder as the language of natural science in the imaginary world which I described” (After Virtue 2, After Virtue 256).

IEP continues

People in the modern liberal capitalist world talk as though we are engaged in moral reasoning, and act as though our actions are chosen as the result of such reasoning, but in fact neither of these things is true. Just as with the people working with “science” in the imaginary world that MacIntyre describes, philosophers and ordinary people are working today with bits and pieces of philosophies which are detached from their original pre-Enlightenment settings in which they were comprehensible and useful. Current moral and political philosophies are fragmented, incoherent, and conflicting, with no standards that can be appealed to in order to evaluate their truth or adjudicate the conflicts between them – or at least no standards that all those involved in the disputes will be willing to accept, since any standard will presuppose the truth of one of the contending positions. To use an analogy that MacIntyre does not use, one might say that it is as if we tore handfuls of pages from books by Jane Austen, Shakespeare, Danielle Steele, Mark Twain, and J.K. Rowling, threw half of them away, shuffled the rest, stapled them together, and then tried to read the “story” that resulted. It would be incoherent, and any attempt to describe the characters, plot, or meaning would be doomed to failure. On the other hand, because certain characters, settings, and bits of narrative would reappear throughout, it would seem as though the story could cohere, and much effort – ultimately futile – might be expended in trying to make it do so. This, according to MacIntyre, is the moral world in which we currently live.
From IEP on Alasdair MacIntyre

6. Voltaire
His quote is famous

If God did not exist we would need to invent Him.
Voltaire

What is not so easily realized that Voltaire's and our world's are very different.  For Voltaire, God not existing was a wild counterfactual, in today's world it is the norm!
Tom Holland
Finally, secularism is just Christianity in a new format.  This is the thesis of Tom Holland's magnum opus Dominion. A summary:
1. Human Rights

Modern Idea: The belief in universal human rights is foundational to contemporary legal and moral systems.
Christian Formulation: The concept of human rights stems from the Christian idea that all people are made in the image of God (Imago Dei). This intrinsic value attributed to every individual laid the groundwork for the notion that every human being has inherent dignity and worth, deserving of protection and respect.

2. Equality

Modern Idea: The principle of equality asserts that all people, regardless of race, gender, or social status, should have equal rights and opportunities.
Christian Formulation: Christianity's radical message that "there is neither Jew nor Greek, slave nor free, male nor female, for you are all one in Christ Jesus" (Galatians 3:28) challenged the hierarchical structures of the ancient world and promoted a vision of spiritual equality that would later influence social and political equality.

3. Abolition of Slavery

Modern Idea: The movement to abolish slavery was a significant moral and social reform in modern history.
Christian Formulation: The abolitionist movement was driven by Christian activists who believed that slavery was incompatible with Christian teachings. They argued that all people are equal in the eyes of God and that enslaving another human being was a grave sin. Figures like William Wilberforce, who were inspired by their Christian faith, played crucial roles in the abolition of slavery.

4. Charity and Social Welfare

Modern Idea: The practice of charitable giving and the establishment of social welfare systems to support the poor and vulnerable.
Christian Formulation: Early Christian communities were known for their care for the poor and sick, inspired by Jesus' teachings about loving one's neighbor and caring for "the least of these." The establishment of hospitals, orphanages, and charities throughout Christian history set a precedent for modern social welfare systems.

5. Forgiveness and Rehabilitation

Modern Idea: Modern justice systems often emphasize rehabilitation over retribution.
Christian Formulation: The Christian concept of forgiveness and redemption has influenced the idea that wrongdoers can be rehabilitated. The story of the Prodigal Son and Jesus' forgiveness of sinners illustrate the belief in the possibility of repentance and transformation, which has informed modern practices of restorative justice.

6. Secular Humanism

Modern Idea: Secular humanism emphasizes the value and agency of human beings, often without reference to religious doctrines.
Christian Formulation: Secular humanism's focus on the intrinsic worth of individuals and the moral imperative to improve the human condition can be traced back to Christian ethical teachings. Even though secular humanism operates without explicit reference to God, its moral foundations are deeply influenced by the Christian view of human dignity and moral responsibility.

7. Women's Rights

Modern Idea: The advocacy for gender equality and women's rights.
Christian Formulation: While historically the Church has been criticized for its treatment of women, the Christian message included revolutionary ideas about women's value and roles. The veneration of Mary, the recognition of women saints, and Jesus' own interactions with women challenged contemporary norms and contributed to the gradual development of ideas about gender equality.


I'm thinking of writing a Question about whether everything that everyone believes so strongly to be a given external, such as a religious view, is actually the result of how humans happen to be. In other words, what we see is not in the world, but in our 'glasses', so to speak. And, we can't change the glasses so everything seems so bone obvious, but it is really 'us'. I hope I can word it, but it's probably more of a Psychology question, and I know they would close it there instantly (or would just say, "well, duh!") so I don't know.

Belief is the absence of knowledge and the presence of knowledge as you elocutely stated in another answer is not the determinor of worth. You can have a thousand years of knowledge and it is not equitable ro one year of love. You said it!! Or at least scripture did. Absolute respect for that !!

@ScottRowe Please see above comment !!

You seem like a practical resourceful man. That's able to determine their own future and able to reason absolute exhaustive logic in a practical situation. Such as diagnosing an engines fault or are diagnosing an electrical fault in a ring main or the process of digging a drain from a main watercourse. If you're not practical your, ost likely political that is unable to deter,ine practical events. Either way your sentient and not a non player character?

@ScottRowe  There is this recent Joe Rogan conversation that talks of Carl Jung saying exactly that — What ppl call God is really the messages from the collective unconscious

So I'm saying, what if the collective unconscious is really the messages from how each separate person just happens to be? We're projecting our individual experience on the world. And those inner experiences are very similar for all of us. We came from only 6 mothers, after all.

You're not going to get a unified answer here -- this is a philosophy site after all ;)
My perspective is that for the most part, "good" and "evil" are absolute for all practical purposes (FAPP). This is not because of some deep metaphysical truth, but merely because we are all the same species, with the same set of evolved sensibilities. There are gray areas which take up the vast majority of the active debates (e.g., abortion, LGBTQ+ rights) but you'll be hard pressed to find a society where its seen as totally fine, even "moral" or "virtuous" to kill children, steal property, or lie. There may be varying degrees of punishments for these actions, but nowhere are they lauded as desirable things.
Of course, all bets are off when we go consider the morality of different species (on Earth or hypothetical extraterrestrials).
I can conceive of an intelligent species that values personal liberty above all else (perhaps they evolved as solitary hunters extraordinaire vs our heavy dependence on social groups) so their neural calculus would be very different from us and come across as cruel.
Edited to clarify based on comment from @JustSomeOldMan:
However, as a human, I feel fine saying actions of people like Hitler, Dahmer, Chris Watts, etc are evil (FAPP) whereas helping the poor, volunteering, caring for you kids, etc are good (FAPP). Not in a deep metaphysical sense, but in the sense I've established above.
Anyone who disagrees needs to present reasons why we are wrong (they carry burden of proof) since the majority of humans have been guided by intuition to craft arguments for the widely held views (and these have been subject to repeated attempts by ne'er-do-wells to loosen some of these, in some cases)

Cooperation makes sense because competition is self-defeating. Even wild animals don't fight needlessly because both parties stand to die, either immediately or because of injury. Some humans didn't learn this, apparently.

@ScottRowe I think the merits of competition vs cooperation is beyond the scope of my expertise here but it has been noted by folks even as early as Darwin how much of nature and evolution involves pointless "arms races" that appear to merely maximize the degree of suffering of all parties (the prey has to run harder and longer, the predator expends more energy catching food, goes hungry more etc).

Ok. I was just going off what you said about caring, helping, volunteering - which I would call cooperation. We could call capitalism an arms race scenario. I call it "a spinning machine with no governor", and have likened it to evolution, as you said.

@Annika Just as a point of interest I have seen example of cross species cooperation in whales and humans to the extent that a killer whale, a predator, offering seal gifts to human scuba divers, the mistake by the divers was they did not accept the gift, however the killer whale was not insulted it just scooped up the dead seal and they went on there separate ways . Look it up I'm sure it is on YouTube

I would give +1 if the last two paragraphs are deleted. Especially the last. It is incorrect. Burden of proof lies with anyone making a positive claim of the ways things are.

@JustSomeOldMan - I don't see an issue with the second to last paragraph - can you tell me your perspective on this. As for the last line, in ethics all statements are positive claims (e.g., one ought to murder, one ought NOT to murder, or murder is not a morally relevant action [like drinking a glass of water]), but some are more widely and generally uncontroversially held than others. In this case, we need to use a different criteria for burden of proof, which is disagreement with the majority.

@JustSomeOldMan - given you were OK with my earlier paragraphs, my second-to-last is merely an implication of that. The actions of those individuals (not eating, breathing, but morally relevant ones like enabling the Holocaust) can be called evil FAAP, in the human context. I can support this by appeal to my sensibilities and common sense and consequentialist considerations. If you disagree with an action I have deemed evil by the above lights, you need to tell me why my reasoning is mistaken.

@JustSomeOldMan a similar dynamic happens with negative atheism vs theism -- a theist give a justification of their view. The atheist cannot just say "I don't hold that view and you shouldn't either" but will need to engage with the logic and explain why it's wrong or they should change their mind.
Perhaps I need to clarify the last paragraph to mention that the majority view CAN give reasons for their ethical beliefs, so to dissent you need to explain why those reasons are invalid.

Curiously, I happen to agree with @JustSomeOldMan. [You have two +1s waiting!!]

@Rushi -- i see where you are coming from -- for example, in theological debates it's often stated that theists are the ones who need to justify their position, as the atheist position is in some sense the "default" view. I used to have this view as well. But the concept of who has the burden/onus is not as clear cut as that. Well-regarded atheist philosophers have questioned this even though it would benefit them to accept it. Key examples are Graham Oppy and Julian Baggini, both of which write about the need for justification in atheism and elsewhere.

@Rushi: here's a good example: "It is evil to kill a newborn baby solely for fun" - who bears the burden of proof here? Would we be allowing such practices until the person who says this provides us an argument that we'd accept? What if we don't think newborns are persons? In that case, we could "fail to accept" this assertion, but only because we are implicitly relying on positive assertions.

@Annika Start by imagining yourself an Aztec king...

JFTR I " agree" with @JustSomeOldMan but probably for different reasons than him: The set {Hitler, Dahmer, Chris Watts} in juxtaposition is weird to the point of being absurd

@Rushi - both you and JustSomeOldMan appear to agree with all but the last two paragraphs. However, the last two paragraphs are written in the context of what I wrote in the earlier parts. I'm not saying that every moral rule is absolute, but there is an effective core of moral rules that are very widespread and are related to the functioning of groups. Outside of that, there is a lot of variation. Also, I specifically kept my statement of "absolute" to a pragmatic type vs metaphycial (I don't think there are true right and wrong actions out there outside of a sociobilogical context)

@Rushi - for the second to last paragraph, the people I put in there are examples where the vast majority of people would call them evil. My last paragraph is basically saying that widely help moral intuitions are usually backed by reasons, so it is the person who wants to change the prevailing view who needs to show why it's wrong.

+1 This is the right answer. The whole point of philosophy is to ask questions and develop a viewing lens, there are different philosophical stances that claim absolutes i.e., moral objectivism and other that claim moral relativism so your answer is the only right answer.

@Annika I began reading your answer but stopped when you raised the question of lesbuan, gay, and transexual rights. Why do those rights trump every other person's rights?  Why aren't human rights the condition of being a human, irespective of gender and ideological identity?  With respect!?

@Annika Just ignore that overlaps paragraph I got my wires crossed somewhere the beggining of which I cannot determine.

@8Mad0Manc8 could you clarify what you’d like time to address? I’m a bit confused by the above; however, seems like your last comment suggests nothing to address?

@Annika Please take no attention to my ent. It was the result of a confusing rout through cyberspace and has no relevance in your answer.God knows how it happened and that is not a metaphysical question ots absolutely certain.

@Annika I'm using  mobile phone to ask and address questions its not easy to determine the correct use of this system sorry!!!

@Annika and the expected result of input and the actual output. Sorry

@Annika morality is based upon the collective good. Democracy is meant to be an extension of a collective vote upon a question of morality. I do not know the premise of undemocratic systems but can only deduce they are not of a vote of morality but a an unjust definition of reality that is absent of vote!!!

@Annika Please pay attention to my last comment?

@Annika is evil the determination that a collective good is false? and no matter how you try to convince that subject too the contrary they deny your argument. I have cross examined pedophiles and they are reluctant to even discuss the subject of  morality in those terms!!

@Annika Evil is Evil and Good is Good there is no relative position, never the twain shall meet!

@Community all that is bullshit morality is determined by the golden rule as is  as Jo wehler answered he's an out an out atheist but at least he can execute a solid argument!!

This answer seems wrong. It is not absolute for practical purposes, it only makes it common. Absoluteness and commonality are not the same concepts.
It is also very mistaken. Nazis saw desirable to kill Jews and undesirable to maintain them. Rpsits see desirable the act of forceful sex.
There's also no relation as to what even is meant by good/evil. It seems you are trying to make a description from commonality, and that doesn't entail the requirement of weight or imperative function of morality. At best, it's a mistaken sociological and psychological description not moral or philos

@Sismetic -- correct, I've sidestepped the whole philosophical debate (I point out in my answer that fundamentally morals are NOT absolute in a metaphysical sense). I decided to step back and say that despite all the hand wringing about relativism, out shared brain architectures does allow for some areas of commonality - to want to be murdered is considered signs of cognitive issues, not "alternative ethics".

@Annika
Sure. But my response wasn't about the metaphysical sense but the practical sense in which you used it. In the practical sense, it is wrong.
"It is not absolute for practical purposes, it only makes it common."
As an example, we can say that practically all humans are mortal. This needs not be a metaphysical absolute, but it would be a practical absolute. This also does nothing to resolve the practical question because it's obvious that practically all matters of problematic behaviour arise despite the narrative of commonality of good behaviour

The relevant context is not the desire to want to be murdered but rather to murder, which practically is very common (Besides the obvious error of relating the mental and the ethical with the brain architecture). So, it leaves us no theoretical or practical knowledge beyond: "some people have acted in some ways and others in another, and sometimes the opposite is true".
The statement of cognitive issues imports an essentialist view beyond the mere descriptive and leads us back to theory and not praxis.
Acting selfishly or "evil" is not a cognitive issue. It can be the opposite, in fact.

@Sismetic Good and bad are relative to ends - murder is bad because we don't want to be murdered (and most of us are hard wired for empathy anyway) that doesn't mean it doesn't still happen but most people don't want it to happen to them or those they care about. As you say" ...all matters of problematic behaviour arise despite the narrative of commonality of good behaviour" ... it is only problematic because it goes against very commonly held desires -- it would just be "behaviour" if that weren't the case. My post is along the lines of Rawls' objective ethics.

@Sismetic the basic idea is simple -- there are a core set of things that we all want (and a LOT of things only some of us want). Those core things (think Maslow) can form the basis for a human "objective" ethics (as much as we can have one). It also explains when we have high chance of conflict (differing core wants) - Rawl's deals with that in his Political Liberalism paper. However, I would venture to say sociologists and anthropologists can find such a common core (with a LOT of window dressing).

@Sismetic - might be easier to continue further in chat if you feel the need to. You can also post an answer as a counterpoint.

@Annika
I have opened a chat:
https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154366/annkia-and-sismetic-ethics-discussion
Also, I did post an answer, if you're interested:
https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/115313/76047

Good and evil are relative, culturally dependent concepts that are reflective of which behaviors have been evolutionarily beneficial for those cultures and societies to encourage and discourage over time.
Much like the physical characteristics of a species over the course of its evolution, the definitions of what constitutes good and evil are constantly in flux as codes of morality mutate, differentiate, and compete for fitness.
Contrary to what other answers to this question assert, it's hard to point to any moral absolutes that have been universally shared across all cultures over time. Even infanticide has been well documented as being regularly practiced by many cultures and viewed by them as just and good—whether for ritual sacrifice, as a method of destroying competing cultures, or as a way of conserving resources or strengthening themselves through preferential self-selection of the strongest.
An increasingly globalized world has contributed to the slow and often violent process of homogenization of the definitions of good and evil across cultures, but even if they do become mostly homogenized at some point in the distant future, they will remain in flux and wholly relative to what was most evolutionarily beneficial during that process of homogenization—and not some cosmic absolute.

There's an ancient Chinese story about good vs bad, which in morality terms is usually expressed as good vs evil. The specific story I'm talking about is a family that loses a horse and their only son breaks a leg, who eventually avoids having to go to war because of the broken leg. The link above tells it better and in more detail.
This shows that what is good or bad/evil is relative, and that it can change drastically given time, circumstances, socially, and even individually. Religion likes to take it to extremes of black and white, while ignoring the grays in between, calling everything that's bad is evil. If you are asking philosophy as a secular discipline, then there isn't anything evil, just bad. And both "good" and "bad" have an extremely wide range of meaning because it's a secular view.
For example, killing in the form of murder is really bad, but killing as a soldier during a war isn't as bad. And killing to lawfully execute a criminal can be considered good for society, depending on societal norms. Or killing rodents and insects can be considered quite good to avoid disease and losing resources needed for humans. However, killing pollinators is considered bad, since we need them to grow food, but it's not as bad as murder. Killing a pet is usually considered bad, unless it's to relieve them of the extreme pain of disease, age, or injury, and then it's both good and bad. Killing an animal for food has no universal moral answer to it being good or bad, and neither does killing one specific type of animal versus another.
So, yes, good and bad are relative. You can be glad your pet isn't in pain anymore (good), but also be sad that they aren't around anymore (bad). And those two viewpoints can even have different weights depending on what kind of day you are having. And those viewpoints can even happen simultaneously, such as being glad your pet is no longer in pain, but also really wanting them around to comfort you or play with you.

I've heard this story before, made a note of it too. Thanks for the gentle reminder.

I love this story -- we have the one Yeshi's Luck from Tibetan Tales for Little Buddhas

Some days I like this story, some days I don't :-)

Thanks for the answer and it is a good example of the relative nature of good and evil. My primary concern though is someone's definition of evil the same definition  of some other person's good. It may be a little deeper than the relatively you depict in a good event or a bad event. I have been a prison guard in charge of a lot of evil people and there conception of good differs entirely from the perception of good you depict.

@8Mad0Manc8, what I've described is the general (but not universal) opinion of current civilized societies. Prison is a distinct microcosm all on it's own, and even different prisons are different microcosms. I'm sure that's even true within different cell blocks within a single prison. And the reason most prisoners are there is because they (or at least their actions) didn't conform to the more general morals of the society that put them there. You perceive them as "evil" and they may perceive themselves as survivors of the miserable choices that were made for them.

(cont.) Your perceptions are based on you agreeing with the society you are part of, or maybe it's a religious doctrine you believe. Either way, this shows that morals are very relative to even the individual and not just a society. It may have been immoral to shoot someone, but it may be considered more immoral to let your kids starve to death because you couldn't get them the food you stole because someone got in your way. Some may think it's immoral for people to imprison an innocent person simply because it gets good ratings at the polls to "find the killer", even though they didn't.

@computercarguy are you in charge of anything important? In your working life? No offence but your reasoning does not suggest a professional aptitude.

@8Mad0Manc8, and some people find it perfectly moral to shoot someone who is a different skin color, because racism. Most societies find it morally acceptable to shoot someone in self defense in various different situations, even if a prosecutor finds a way to skew the shooting into looking like something other then self-defense. And that prosecutor might find it perfectly moral to do so to maintain their perfect record in court. So again, it just shows that morals are basically infinitely relative on not only the individual, the situation, but also nearly anything and everything else.

@8Mad0Manc8, I'm only describing the morals I see in others. Nothing I've said here describes my own morals.

@8Mad0Manc8, I'm definitely not a precog, since I can't understand what you just said. I'm sorry, but the spelling and incorrect grammar of your last comment makes it incomprehensible to me. Can you fix that?

@computercarguy I'm pissed I've had 10 pints of beer my grammar reflects my inebriation, does yours lol

@8Mad0Manc8, this isn't social media. You should probably stay off this site until you are sober and ready for a well reasoned consideration of what people are posting.

@computercarguy I'm never of the drink how doy ou think1 anyone can compose a logical  relevant argument if it's not under the effect off nebriation. The absolute definition even aristotle and Epicures they were all practising alcholhilucs and di not have a pot ro piss in nor a window to throw it out!!!

@computercarguy  If your British then you may understand look up the Scottish series Rab C Nesbitt you'll learn a lot about working class philosophy and philosophy in general

@computercarguy so you and every other soul are not the subject of redemption for yours or their actions?

@8Mad0Manc8, that's a completely unrelated question. You should do more research on that topic on you own before considering asking it on this Stack, since I'm sure there are plenty of other questions along that lines here.

I think the issue here is that you cannot have an absolute morality without a universal frame of reference that everyone has the same amount of access to. Humans (especially societies, as has been pointed out in other comments) trending away from murder, stealing, etc. is practical, but still relative to the society.
The motive for volunteering at a soup kitchen and recognizing LGBTQ+ rights are derived from the same desire (to do right), but many people view both activities through different lenses. It cannot be absolute because if it were, no human could claim those two activities don't intersect.
We often see a collective, loosely agreed upon morality on the level of society, but that isn't an example of a universal morality that applies to all beings.

Absoluteness of evil is relative to religious framing
In Christianity Evil is absolute; in most other religions it's relative to some more superordinating ontology.
Only in Christianity is evil made into a noun and then capitalized — Evil! Variously symbolized as Adam, serpent etc. Or directly personified: Satan, Lucifer...

In Hinduism the superordinating ontology is Brahman-Maya — reality-error. And in addition to maya, the erroring tendency is also variously termed
moha,
ahankar etc.
In Buddhism the superordinating ontology is
dukha-nirvana — suffering-release, and the suffering tendency is
tanha
In Taoism I suspect the notion of Evil is so far away it could hardly be even given a vague equivalent. [But I am no Taoist expert]

The Modern Secular World
The difficulty of our time is that Christianity has been kicked out by secularism but not the addiction we inherit from it to calling others evil. So now we have «secular evil» eg. "terrorist", "racist", "Nazi" etc.
It's a worldview much more dystopian than the Christian one because in the latter there was evil (from Adam) and redemption (from Christ).
Now there is only evil, no redemption, and under newer and newer fashionable names!

No worries I just deleted my comment because I thought I'd put it to  another answer with regard to Adam and Eve. Now it's lost in cyber space. Lol

This doesn't seem to answer the question, which is looking for a non-religious viewpoint on whether good and evil are absolute.

@Sean Maybe you missed the last 3 paragraphs?? Anyways... I've made it more clear with a section heading

Those read like a diatribe against secularism, and don't seem to assert a viewpoint on whether good and evil are relative or absolute.

@Sean Try taking off your prejudice lenses; you'll  see no diatribe. The answer can be summarized: (1) Christianity: evil is absolute (2)Eastern religions There are more fundamental  ontologies, evil is subsidiary there  (3) Modern secularism is Christianity in disguise and without the redemptions

Do Eastern beliefs reward good behaviour by ascendance or reward bad behaviour by acendance or is the determinor of acendance grey?

@Sean Also you need to read the question. It asks: How does philosophy deal with these two concepts? not what is the non religious view of these concepts?

@8Mad0Manc8 What is ascendance? First time I am hearing the word. Web search says its a noun from ascend

@8Mad0Manc8 Karma, dharma and ritam rule over all — including God! Roughly translatable as: Outer law, inner law, cosmic law. So much so that even Ram (God) is compelled to be born and suffer by karma.  In many respects the Ram story and the Jesus story are analogous — the human suffering, the rejection and abandonment by his own etc.  But the mechanism that orchestrates the suffering is quite contrasting from the Christian

@Rishi You might be able to school me from a lack of knowledge of Eastern belief but as far as I know it to be holistic and the world is not reducible to A or Not A there are greys between right and wrong or good and evil however there is a lineage of beings within this world and an ascendance between these beings is a reward for commendable behaviour until you reach nirvana a place where there is no acendance from.

@8Mad0Manc8 You mean by ascendance "becoming better; becoming more holy; coming nearer to God etc..."??  You might like Nagarjuna. [And do remember: Christianity, Judaism, Islam are all originating in the east for the western world! Heck! Even the Greeks are more east than most of the "West"!!]

This is not a dodge I have not experienced heaven or hell and similarly I have not experienced nirvana. From whatever belief you hold and this is not condescending statement all of this is speculative. I just believe there is one truth and I believe it to be the truth regardless of which approach you adopt to gain knowledge of it, Eastern holism or Western reductionism.

@8Mad0Manc8 You will see I agree with your last comment, perhaps more than you imagine. See eg.

@Rishi I agree there is a commonality between faiths with regard to spirit. I have no denomination religiously speaking, but I pray for those who think they do not possess spirit, or a soul.

So people who have a nice life think everything is fine, and others think there are huge problems and threats. Seems a lot like the natural world, really. The secular solution is to alleviate the problems and end the threats, and things get better for people. It does work, but yeah, there's no goalpost. People who need goalposts are left out, others think it's fine. So we create goals for people: education, a career path, family life, and they either rebel, or selfish people move the goalposts out of reach. Maybe we should look out for our self-interests in a more global way?

The difference between absolute and relative may be more relative than absolute.
Across different societies and cultural traditions (including religious traditions), I believe that the only more or less unchanging, more or less universally accepted moral value is the one expressed by the golden rule. This rule expresses a kind of intuitive sense of fairness - a sense that all members of the group should be treated equally - which happens to also be shared with primates (see for instance Frans De Waal's books, or Sarah F. Brosnan Justice- and fairness-related behaviors in nonhuman primates).
The problem with the golden rule is that it still allows very different
realizations. For instance, is the huge gap in individual possessions and political power between the world's billionaires and other people fair? In some societies or groups it might be considered fair (argument: everybody has in principle the same opportunities to amass an obscene amount of money), but in others it could be seen as totally unfair and a justification for revolution. (Of course, human nature being what it is, the kleptocrats now are also dominant in countries that did have a socialist revolution...)
Brosnan's article also gives a short explanation of game-theoretical
studies of fairness, in particular the so-called Ultimatum Game - a way to study if and how fairness can be established in a context of negotiation. The game involves two players and consists of two consecutive moves. The first player has some amount of money (or any kind of sharable resource); their move is to split that amount any way they like. The second player then moves and only has the option to either accept or reject the split. If they accept, then each gets their share accordingly; if not, then nobody gets anything.
This game has been studied across very different cultures for the last 40 years (and even with primates too). The ideal, Kantian 'fair' split, you might say, is 50-50. And it definitely seems reasonable to accept that split (if you are the second player). But the game really models a potential "race to the bottom", since it's "rational" (in one's best interest) to accept any split rather than nothing and it's rational also to offer the split that is as high as possible for one self. In other words, the game has infinitely many stable equilibria (one for each possible split apart from 100%-0% which can always be rejected), but tempts the first player to go as low (in their offer to the second) as they can get away with!
In actual outcomes it turns out that most people in current, industrialized societies offer a split of about 60% (for me) - 40% (for you), and this is usually accepted by the second player. Apparently most people think that's "fair enough". It's interesting to see that in pre-industrial, extremely egalitarian, so-called primitive cultures the first player tends to offer a much lower split (about 16% for the other, if I remember correctly). It's interesting to consider what this means for the apparent sense of fairness expressed in these actions.

Note: Brosnan claims in the introduction of here overview article

In fact, only English has a word for the concept of “fairness”; other languages have adopted the English word, indicating a culturally broad interest in the concept but potentially implying that the concept is not ubiquitous.

It is simply not true that only English has a word for "fairness" (or "fair"). For instance French has "équitable"; Dutch has "eerlijk" ("eerlijk delen") or "gelijk". Modern Chinese has 公平 (gōngpíng) (this very neutrally expresses the concept of a shared/common/public (gōng) balanced/equal (píng) good). The same term can already be found in preimperial classical Chinese (for instance in Xúnzǐ or HánFēizǐ). Other languages no doubt also have words that are not imported from the anglosaxon world.

Given that you are supposedly asking from a secular perspective, I will have to say that depending on the meaning the categories are fallacious(neither relative nor absolute) or relative.
Why is that? Because if one takes the concept to be tied to an external and superior standard(for example, requiring an imperative function, the so called but ambiguous 'normativity') then there's no proper horizon from which to derive such a value for the subject is self-referential in its will and freedom. As such, no externality can import its own value unto the subject nor command over it, especially impersonal objects(like abstract 'justice', 'human rights', or 'good'). At most, the subject will reproduce and replicate such values internally and from it derive its own law. Yet, this self-law is internal and not truly externally sourced(even if it may relate to external objects). As such, the very concept of ethics(in the traditional sense) within secularism must be deemed fallacious.
If we speak of a weaker sense(whose membership as a proper sense of the term/concept is disputable and has been heavily disputed), we must import the relation of value. Even for contemporary concepts of 'reason', these moral reasons are conceived as intrinsically valuable(which falls under the incoherence above). The alternative is to conceive of things not in an intrinsic sense but in an extrinsic sense. An internal relation of meanings and values held by the subject in a self-referential sense. This is obviously relative as there's no absolute view of the subject upon which to derive an absolute sense of value, and even if an hypothetical could be conceived, it would still lack the self-relation to ground it as properly universal vs "objective". This self-referentiality of value, btw, is deeply problematic, but a radical secularist may hold the existence of it as a self-evident phenomenological event even if arbitrary(no external ground).
Secular ethics is nonsensical in various ways. This is a very profound argument against secularism

It’s a very controversial question.Nobody can give you a certain answer.And I need to remind we should avoid early conclusions.But I can help you learn the reasons behind different theories I know.
“Good and Evil are relative “usually leads to moral relativism(MR).Yeah,my discussion scoop is only the “moral relativism “.
In philosophy,some people support MR because empirical fact.They putted forward Descriptive Moral Relativism(DMR),it is seen as experiential. DMR is more of a descriptive position,it dependent on “experimental philosophy “. However,there is a more expanded relativism called Metaethical Moral Relativism(MMR),It arose from philosophical reflections(it seems that MMR is more philosophical),it explored the essence of relativism.MMR thinks we will have moral disagreements when we in the different moral frameworks, they grant that we will resolve disagreements when the parties to a moral dispute share a same moral framework.Someone also support moral relativism because of cultural diversity .
Both DMR and MMR （there are other less popular ways to classify MR,they are included) think moral judgments(like good and evil)are not absolute.And they all deny that any standpoint is uniquely privileged over all others.(Quote:IEP-relativism).
Predictably, they will face a lot of opposition.One of the most popular opposition(it’s also the strongest one )is it leads to moral confusion.In some extreme cases,we can not even judge an apparent crime and punish it because the criminal have a different moral framework（like he can call himself from a cannibal）.And we have almost completely denied moral progress .Another opposition is the difficulty of practice.In fact,it’s not easy to treat different moral viewpoints fairly,our moral believes are bond to be emotional invested.That’s because our moral frameworks have gone to be a part of ourselves in our growing up process.In other words,it modeled us.So in a concrete sense,it’s almost impossible to understand or accept a viewpoint which is totally different with ours.
There is one another interesting opposition.This interesting theory said  relativism(not only MR)is self-contradictory.When we say the moral relativism is a truth,it has already violated itself.Because we can only say it is true when it is in our moral/social/culture framework.
There are some mixed ideas.To sum them up,we called it “moral minimalism”.Personally, I prefer this position.On the one hand,they admit that sometimes we really can’t to make moral agreements .On the other hand,we should have some fundamental agreements.That’s because in the angle of naturalism,human beings have the similar life habits(living in groups),we have the same body structure…To survive in the nature ,all of humans need to agree and follow these rules.And they also argued that moral relativism overlooked culture spread.
That’s all I know.Thanks for reading.

Morality is a set of rules to control the social behaviour of humans.

These rules are taken over by the individuals educated in a given
group. But they can also be questioned by some individuals during
their further development, see Laurence Kohlberg's Stages of moral
development. The reason for questioning are learning new arguments
or e.g., making new experiences according to the Golden
Rule.
From a binary point of view moral rules assess certain values as
good or evil. Values, which underly the intention or the behaviour.
Hence the values are relative alike the relativity of the rules. But
certain rules are widespread because they ensure the stability of
nearly all social groups.


I think the golden rule is everybody's definition and determiner of morality even those that have faith and those that don't  Can you argue the golden rule isn't a universal absolute of a reasoning being?

We have an innate sense of fairness that we share with other primates - and I suspect also with dophins and whales.

@8Mad0Manc8 The burden to argue first lies on those who consider the Golden Rule to be an ultimate justification in ethics.

@JoWehler That old chestnut  lol

@8Mad0Manc8 History shows plenty of examples of reasoning beings that follow "Might is Right" morality, so the golden rule is far from universal

@Indigenuity they may be human and reasoning however do you consider them to concur with how you determine your morality or are you a person that says the only limit of your behaviour is what is actually possible and that is the limiting factor to your behaviour?


The philosophical doctrine of animalism is that humans are basically the same as any other animal, in sharing the characteristics of being physical and instinctive.

The animals at the top of the food chain have to kill to survive.  They don't see killing as evil.  Humans club baby seals to death to sell their valuable fur, bought by other humans who create a market for it.  Good and evil are ideas in the minds of humans who have lost the connection to the animal world.  Their instincts become dull, and their logic becomes confused. Belief in God is proof of my statements.  Good and evil are chained to the idea of some absolute moral authority, who will judge us after we die.  Thus enters the notion that we must obey our parents, and be good children.  Wild animals are unfettered by the purely human notions of good and evil.  I personally couldn't kill a child of my own species, but that's just me.  Abortion doctors don't share my mental acuity, but then again their species developed and used the atomic bomb, to kill adults and children indiscriminately, so they don't surprise me.  And most likely, terrorists will do the same thing to us here in safe America one day.  We will call them evil, and they will consider themselves good. The idiocy will remain, until humans go extinct.

Suppose the newborn mammal is helpless, to some degree, and needs to interact with an external parent or caregiver. Mother Bear Man, for example, is a biologist in New Hampshire who teaches orphan bear cubs how to survive in the wilderness by acting as a substitute mother. Mammals should associate biological sense of good or evil with the presence or absence of the mother. Human fathers, like mother bears, produce and share resources and defend against threats in nature. Humans are like the lower animals; yet we have developed tribal, social, and psychological experiences of good and evil.

When you say "Belief in God is proof of my statements" you mean that belief supports dull and confused thinking?

@ScottRowe, there's nothing dull or confused about the way my species thinks.

You said that people lose their connection to the animal world. Is that linked to belief in God, since that's how the wording seems to read?

@ScottRowe, those children that are induced by their parents to believe in God lose their connection to the animal world... that is the inevitable consequence.  Those parents are atheists, who would club a baby seals to death or become an abortion doctor or approve an atomic bomb blast in Hiroshima or shoot a grocery store clerk for $50 .

While Ive upvoted this answer, your views are more Christianity-specific than you perhaps realize. See my answer

To imply that abortion doctors must be atheists shows your unfamiliarity with religions other than your own.

There is good and evil but it depends on alignment. Depending on your alignment of your beliefs ,which may be scientific or unscientific (like religion) , good and evil are understood and put into practice.
Different alignments expand and contract , making it possible to achieve absolute good or evil.
Therefore good and evil are relative but absoluteness can be achieved.

>Are Good and Evil relative or absolute?
There IS no good.
There IS no evil.
There is only FLESH.
Read Nietzsche.

If we look at the Bible's morality from a philosophical viewpoint, I think we will see that it gives us a foundation which is absolute and surprisingly simple and elegant.
Natural good corresponds with being intact, healthy, alive, and functional; while natural evil is a destruction of this good.  Examples of natural evils are sickness, wounds, death, physical pain, emotional pain, etc.
When we talk of moral good and evil, we are talking about the will, which includes our desires and decisions.  Moral good stems from a desire for final good toward God and toward others, while moral evil stems from a desire for final evil toward God and toward others.  God commands us to desire and seek the good of our neighbor--who is of equal value with us--to the same extent that we desire and seek our own good; or put more succinctly, as God put it, to "love thy neighbor as thyself".  All of the moral commandments dealing with our relationship toward other people are merely examples and expressions of this basic, absolute principle (James 2:8-11).  If you love your neighbor as yourself, you will not murder him; you will not steal from him; you will not commit adultery with his wife; you will not tell lies about him; you will not covet what he has but will be happy at his success; etc.
Apparent exceptions do not violate the underlying principles, and thus do not make biblical morality relative; for instance, God commanded capital punishment for murder (Genesis 9:6); but this is out of love for the victim and his family, and out of a love of justice.  God does not love the murderer to the exclusion of His love for the victim or His love of justice.  (He can show mercy through the cross of Jesus Christ; but since Jesus bore our punishment, it still does not violate absolute justice; it's mercy at God's own expense.)  Capital punishment thus does not at all excuse murder that has no just cause.  And in a lot of cases, our vision is very cloudy from sin, frailty, and the complexity of life and situations; and so we rely on Someone who is perfectly levelheaded and has perfectly clear vision (hence, the repeated phrase in the Bible, "good in the sight of the LORD").  But God has made the underlying moral principles of good and evil perfectly clear to us, and I believe that biblically, they are absolute and extremely simple!

Jesus said unto him, Thou shalt love the Lord thy God with all thy heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy mind.  This is the first and great commandment.  And the second is like unto it, Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself.  On these two commandments hang all the law and the prophets. (Matthew 22:37-40)


This seems more appropriate for the Christianity Stack Exchange. The asker specifically asks for a non-religious response.

Thanks @Sean--but if the Bible happens to contain a philosophically consistent and elegant formulation of societal morality, wouldn't that qualify it to be within a philosophical discussion?  I.e., if a religion simply has a hodgepodge of societal rules with no backbone, I could see how that wouldn't be appropriate to discuss here.  But the biblical framework has a unifying philosophical consistency, and so wouldn't that make it appropriate to examine from a philosophical viewpoint?

It's contrary to what the asker is asking for. In their first sentence they state they're aware of the religious viewpoints. In their second, they ask for a non-religious viewpoint.

I agree howver the morality of the Christian religion is pretty much the same across cultures and is based upon the golden rule which is do unto others as you would have done by others unto yourself. And this golden rule is the basis as to why cultural and on the whole this principle is universal no matter what race or cultural background you are in.

Are we talking about the bible that says to take your disobedient son to be stoned to death?

@JonathanZ I'm a born Catholic however not a practising Catholic, if my mother's had been indoctrinated to believe that, then I would have been dead a long time ago and wouldn't be making this comment. I don't know that reference in the bible and forgive me for my ignorance of the Christian Faith , but what is the context of that example from the Bible amongst other similar examples of biblical morality?

@JonathanZ--In this case, it was a civil command that required governmental sanction; i.e., from a societal POV, only God could know whether that law would result in more good than harm for society as a whole.  The idea is that the child was quite disobedient and required the parents to publicly explain.  I suspect the mere threat of this law would be enough to virtually prevent it having to be used!  :)  We don't have a recorded use of it in the Bible that I'm aware of.  But it's certainly not a moral command to individuals today, living under different governments.

About the nasty things in the Bible. Every religion has nasty things... if you go about hunting for them. And wonderful things if you go treasure hunting for those.  Ramana Maharshi, one of the foremost non dual teachers of the 20th century was one asked about some of the darker sides of Hinduism. His answer: The central teaching of the Vedas is the atma, the universality of the Self in all and all in the Self. Adhere to that and drop all  the rest as auxiliary arguments.

The same can be done for Christianity . Although Jesus literally reduced Moses' 600+ commandments to 2 [last para above], in practice I believe it works out to about 4-5 (1) Love God (2) Love thy neighbour (3) Forgive all transgressions (and instead  (3a) Turn the other cheek) (4) Judge not lest you be judged

I don't see an issue with referring to religious texts that happen to provide a secular justification of ethics. However, your answer does take a theistic/non-secular view, as shown thy this line "Moral good stems from a desire for final good toward God..." -- the elegant framework you cite goes nowhere if we omit this crucial assumption.

@Annika--True, I do mention God when giving the Bible's foundation of morality, but if we look only at the second commandment ("love thy neighbor as thyself"), I don't think the elegance falls apart.  It's not the complete biblical ethic, of course; but it's still elegant and internally consistent within itself, as far as it goes, which is what James 2:8-11 demonstrates.

@8Mad0Manc8 - Deuteronomy 21:18-21

The Bible is a big old mess, filled with contradictory rules, many good rules, and many absolutely horrific ones too. If some one says "From this mess I can pull a foundation for a good ethics" then that's valid, but there's no way you're not doing a boatload of cutting, pasting, and deleting. "... Exceptions do not violate the underlying principles" is spitting in the face of reasoning - it is the motto of the biblical apologist, who thinks that if they can come up with a series of steps by which something could be true that they have proved that it is true.

On another point, consider that "God commanded capital punishment for murder ...", and this is something that you argue must be maintained. But the same god also commanded the stoning of the disobedient child, and this is "certainly not a moral command to individuals today". How did you decide which holds and which falls? Clearly not by looking in the bible. This morality that you've built clearly has some non-biblical elements in it, but your position crumbles if you date to acknowledge that.

@JonathanZ--Capital punishment is a civil law as well, and not meant to be carried out by individuals against the law--i.e., the government is the one that "bears the sword" (Romans 13:4).  And so you're right that it's not a very good example of an apparent exception to individual moral law, although I will say that the Catholics lately, for instance, are against capital punishment for moral reasons.  My point was that this civil law is consistent with "love thy neighbor as thyself" when government officials carry it out.

Cogito, there's tentative convergence between religious ethics and secular ethics and ergo, neither can claim moral territory, except perhaps on the grounds of I was here first, in which case, religion wins.

@PeterRankin: Please think critically. Suppose my favorite Harry Potter fanfiction contained "a philosophically-consistent and elegant formulation of societal morality"; would you therefore endorse answers which cite it? No, because fiction does not have to contend with the real world as it physically occurs. You could cite Earthsea or The Brothers Karamazov – fiction which is held in high regard for its moral philosophy – and still have the same problem.

Hi @Corbin--I'm not familiar with those works, and so I can't speak to how the philosophy of social morality in them would hold up to scrutiny; I just know that the Bible's does.  I'm not sure I fully understood your point, though--do you think the Bible's social morality is inconsistent, or simply that it shouldn't be discussed philosophically because of where it is found?  I disagree with the assumption that the Bible is fiction; but that aside, wouldn't you need to show how it is inconsistent or impractical, rather than simply dismissing it as originating from the Bible?

I liked where you said that we could start with just "love your neighbor as yourself" and build from there. The only problem I see is that many people are not very good at loving even themselves (a large number murder themselves every year, for example) so it might not work all that well in practice.

That's an interesting thought, @ScottRowe.  I'm not very familiar with that topic, and I'd have to give that case some more thought, but as a partial reply, I'd imagine that even a suicidal person would get upset if someone punched him in the face, or stole his wallet, or tried to kill him against his will during the times he preferred to live.  And so I'd say he still loves himself enough to know not to do those things to other people against their will, and would thus be violating the underlying principle of loving his neighbor as himself in any event.
